# How To Query Top Three Reference ID only and How I can query until 3 Level Group below only Based Reference ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, relationship

I have table like this below where it save all data with reference id :-

```
ID  Name    RefID
A   AAAA    null
B   BBBB    A
C   CCCC    B
D   DDDD    C
E   EEEE    D
F   FFFF    E
```

Firstly I need some query where I can scan which are the top three reference id level only and show up.

--- Example: When D added below C ---

```
GLevel  ID  RefID   No
Start   A       (3)
Level(1)    B   (A) (2)     
Level(2)    C   (B) (1)
Level(3)   D    (C)
```

Result (Down To Top): A,B and C are top three reference id for D
Result (Top to Down): A have B,C and D as child based refid

When E has enter below D, then A are not valid reference id for E. I need to show top three reference id for E.

--- Example: When E added below D ---

```
GLevel  Id  RefID   No
Start   A   
Level(1)    B   (A) (3)
Level(2)    C   (B) (2)
Level(3)   D    (C) (1)
Level(4)   E    (D)
```

Result (Down To Top): D,C and B are top three reference id for E
Result (Top to Down): B have C,D and E as child based refid

As a final result I need to rearrange and store my compute view for each ID till Group Level 3 only like below:-

```
id  GroupLevel  RefID   
A   Level(1)        B   
A   Level(2)        C
A   Level(3)        D
B   Level(1)        C
B   Level(2)        D
B   Level(3)        E
C   Level(1)        D
C   Level(2)        E
D   Level(1)        E
E   null
```

Who have cross this problem please help me how to solve it. Anyway thanks on advance for reading this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgreql version (|| instead of '+' for concatenation and quoted level alias):

```
select ID, 'Level(' || cast(level as varchar(255)) || ')', RefID from (
    select t0.ID, 
    case level.level
        when 1 then t1.ID
        when 2 then t2.ID
        when 3 then t3.ID 
    end RefID,
    level.level
    from Test t0
    left outer join Test t1 on t1.RefID = t0.ID
    left outer join Test t2 on t2.RefID = t1.ID
    left outer join Test t3 on t3.RefID = t2.ID
    cross join (
        select 1 "level" union all
        select 2 union all
        select 3
    ) level
) t
where t.RefID is not null
```

Comment: Hello Rudolf Yurgenson, great solution and very supportive!. That solution already done from one of 3 query I need to build. Ok. Now I need to create query where I can get this result:- 

--- Example: When D added below C ---

GLevel  ID  RefID   No
Start   A       (3)
Level(1)    B   (A) (2)     
Level(2)    C   (B) (1)
Level(3)   D    (C)

Comment: Ok. Now I need to create query where I can get this result:- 

--- Example: When E added below D ---

GLevel  Id  RefID   No
Start   A   
Level(1)    B   (A) (3)
Level(2)    C   (B) (2)
Level(3)   D    (C) (1)
Level(4)   E    (D)
 
When I query like "...... Where ID='D' " I get a result will be C,B and A where 3 level only can listed. It's same process if  i choose ".... Where ID='C' " the result should be show B and A only. Because above A has no data. The result should be different if I choose "...... Where ID='E' " where A are not listed. Can it done on single query only?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Test(
  ID varchar(10),
  Name varchar(10),
  RefID varchar(10)
)

insert into Test
select 'A','AAAA',null union all
select 'B','BBBB','A' union all
select 'C','CCCC','B' union all
select 'D','DDDD','C' union all
select 'E','EEEE','D' --union all
--select 'F','FFFF','E'

select ID, 'Level(' + cast(level as varchar(255)) + ')' GroupLevel, RefID from (
  select t0.ID, 
    case level.level
      when 1 then t1.ID
      when 2 then t2.ID
      when 3 then t3.ID 
    end RefID,
    level.level
  from Test t0
    left outer join Test t1 on t1.RefID = t0.ID
    left outer join Test t2 on t2.RefID = t1.ID
    left outer join Test t3 on t3.RefID = t2.ID
    cross join (
      select 1 level union all
      select 2 union all
      select 3
    ) level
) t
where t.RefID is not null
```

Output:

```
ID | GroupLevel | RefID |
---+------------+-------+
A  | Level(1)   | B     |
A  | Level(2)   | C     |
A  | Level(3)   | D     |
B  | Level(1)   | C     |
B  | Level(2)   | D     |
B  | Level(3)   | E     |
C  | Level(1)   | D     |
C  | Level(2)   | E     |
D  | Level(1)   | E     |
```

Not sure that I understand what should happen with F. Also, can't see any logic behind 'E null' row in your desired output

Comment: Thanks you Rudolf Yurgenson for your quick reply. I will test your solution and get back the result.

Comment: Hello, I try last night your solution but I cannot produce the output. That query stuck on "select 1 level union all" where error come out is "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "level" ".

Comment: Looks like your rdbms treats "level" alias as a keyword. Rename it or wrap with quotes or square brackets or what else is used by your rdbms. And it's better to specify which rdbms you use.

Comment: Looks like you are using postgresql, I've added postgresql version in another answer

Answer (score 0):

Rudolf Yurgenson.

Firstly, thanks you so much for your solution given.

I attach the output from your solution below:-

[Result: View Group Level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrGeI.png)

I saw ID A print twice for B as you can see on my attachment others are perfect generating sequence group level based refid. Do you think because I start key-in others data or we need to change a little bit of query you have make?.

*"It's unreadable. – Rudolf Yurgenson"*

Ok. Now I need to create query where I can get this result:-

-- Example: When E added below D ---

GLevel  Id  RefID   No
Start   A
Level(1)    B   (A) (3)
Level(2)    C   (B) (2)
Level(3)   D    (C) (1)
Level(4)   E    (D)

When I query like "**...... Where ID='D'** " I get a result ***C,B and A where 3 level only can listed.*** 
It's same process if i choose ".... Where ID='C' " the result should be show B and A only. Because above A has no data. 
The result should be different if I choose "...... Where ID='E' " where A are not listed and result should be D,C and B only.

I think using SELECT TOP(3) but still idea not on my head to write it.

Comment: >I saw ID A print twice for B - that's because of two records (C, C1) joined to B. I.e. there are two different branches in our tree - A,B,C... and A,B,C1... But in our case we need just one record - A,B. It can easily be fixed by adding 'distinct' - 'select distinct ID, 'Level(' ....'

Answer (score 0):

So, you have reversed task that outputs ancestors.

This is a simple query that returns first three ancestors (first one is a parent and etc.) in columns:

```
select t0.ID, t1.ID ancestor1, t2.ID ancestor2, t3.ID ancestor3
from Test t0
left outer join Test t1 on t0.RefID = t1.ID
left outer join Test t2 on t1.RefID = t2.ID
left outer join Test t3 on t2.RefID = t3.ID
```

Result is:

```
|ID|Ancestor1|Ancestor2|Ancestor3|
+--+---------+---------+---------+
|A |NULL     |NULL     |NULL     |
|B |A        |NULL     |NULL     |
|B1|A        |NULL     |NULL     |
|B2|A        |NULL     |NULL     |
|B4|A        |NULL     |NULL     |
|C |B        |A        |NULL     |
|C1|B        |A        |NULL     |
|D |C        |B        |A        |
|E |D        |C        |B        |
|F |E        |D        |C        |
```

Modified pivot version:

```
select ID, level, ancestor from (
  select distinct
    t0.ID,
    case level.level
      when 1 then t1.ID
      when 2 then t2.ID
      when 3 then t3.ID
    end ancestor, level
  from Test t0
  left outer join Test t1 on t0.RefID = t1.ID
  left outer join Test t2 on t1.RefID = t2.ID
  left outer join Test t3 on t2.RefID = t3.ID
  cross join (
    select 1 as level union all
    select 2 union all
    select 3
  ) level
) t where t.ancestor is not null
order by 1, 2
```

Result:

```
ID Level Ancestor
B   1   A
B1  1   A
B2  1   A
B4  1   A
C   1   B
C   2   A
C1  1   B
C1  2   A
D   1   C
D   2   B
D   3   A
E   1   D
E   2   C
E   3   B
F   1   E
F   2   D
F   3   C
```

Comment: Thanks you. This also perfect what I want. Are this query run faster compare the last once your given?

Comment: I forget to ask regarding count(*) for each level where Ancestor='A'. I just need the result show like this:- Ancestor, Level, Total. I try put count statement on above solution but can get a result correctly.

Comment: I don't understand what should be displayed in this total :(

Comment: I think I will open new thread regarding this feature matter.

Comment: This is the link :     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621931/how-to-count-and-sum-with-related-table-in-case-outer-join-level/35626250#35626250