# How To Count and Sum in Same Table To Become Parent Dataset

Tags: sql, asp.net, postgresql, gridview, dataset

This is extended from [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171909/how-to-query-top-three-reference-id-only-and-how-i-can-query-until-3-level-group) regarding Query Top Three Reference ID. Since "level" column become dynamic and I need to keep it while display on gridview.

My plan to create 2 dataset (Parent and Child).

1)

Regarding Child Dataset already have a answer (thanks to Rudolf) like below:-

Table Test

```
ID  Name    RefID
A   AAAA    null
B   BBBB    A
C   CCCC    B
D   DDDD    C
E   EEEE    D
F   FFFF    E
```

Sql Statement

```
select ID, 'Level(' + cast(level as varchar(255)) + ')' GroupLevel, RefID from (
      select t0.ID, 
        case level.level
          when 1 then t1.ID
          when 2 then t2.ID
          when 3 then t3.ID 
        end RefID,
        level.level
      from Test t0
        left outer join Test t1 on t1.RefID = t0.ID
        left outer join Test t2 on t2.RefID = t1.ID
        left outer join Test t3 on t3.RefID = t2.ID
        cross join (
          select 1 level union all
          select 2 union all
          select 3
        ) level
    ) t
    where t.RefID is not null
```

Output:

```
ID | GroupLevel | RefID |
---+------------+-------+
A  | Level(1)   | B     |
A  | Level(2)   | C     |
A  | Level(3)   | D     |
B  | Level(1)   | C     |
B  | Level(2)   | D     |
B  | Level(3)   | E     |
C  | Level(1)   | D     |
C  | Level(2)   | E     |
D  | Level(1)   | E     |
```

Now I need to create Parent Dataset like below:-

Output in GridView with "+" and "-"

```
Introducer  Level      Total Id
A           Level (1)      2
-   Id  Name
    --  -----
    B   BBBB
    C   CCCC

A           Level(2)       1
-   Id  Name
    --  -----
    D   DDDD
```

Before that, I need to create sql statement with Count(*) to get total id based table above. I try many time to place it on Rudolf statement but can get total correctly:-

```
select ID, 
'Level(' + cast(level as varchar(255)) + ')' GroupLevel, 
RefID,

*second try - result error
     count(*) as reccount* 

from (
      select t0.ID, 
        case level.level
          when 1 then t1.ID
          when 2 then t2.ID
          when 3 then t3.ID 
        end RefID,

*first try - result count double
           count(*) as reccount*

        level.level
      from Test t0
        left outer join Test t1 on t1.RefID = t0.ID
        left outer join Test t2 on t2.RefID = t1.ID
        left outer join Test t3 on t3.RefID = t2.ID
        cross join (
          select 1 level union all
          select 2 union all
          select 3
        ) level
    ) t
    where t.RefID is not null
```

I can figure out where to put count statement to get total record based level group.

2)

I also need to add column and sum value from any related table. Let say I have table child for each id like below:-

Table Child

```
ID  Date Join   Child
B   XX/XX/XXXX  2
C   XX/XX/XXXX  5
```

My desire output should be:-

```
Introducer  Level      Total Id Total Child 
A           Level (1)   2        7  
-   Id  Name    Date Join   Child
    --  ----    ---------   -----
    B   BBBB    XX/XX/XX    2
    C   CCCC    XX/XX/XX    5
A           Level(2)    1        0  
-   Id  Name    Date Join   Child
    --  ----    ---------   ------
    D   DDDD    XX/XX/XX    Null
```

I am very appreciate and thanks on advance for yours time and read this thread and hope anybody cross this problem have a solutions regarding this questions please share with me.

Thanks you.

Comment: Your data looks like a plain linked list (A->B->C->D->E->F) to me, but inverted (RefId is a parent pointer) Where do the date_join and count() / child /total child stem from? Why is D->Child == NULL in the final output (D still has child E and grandchild F, IIUC)

Comment: Please improve the result formatting, it's unreadable. First is okay, second is good but the rest don't align well.

Comment: Hello, Thanks joop and Jakub Kania for your time and reply. Let me fix unreadable output first. Do you think where I suppose to put Count(*) to get total record for each level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for question no 2

" *I also need to add column and sum value from any related table. Let say I have table child for each id like below:-*

**Table Child**

```
ID  Date Join   Child
B   XX/XX/XXXX  2
C   XX/XX/XXXX  5
```

On sql statement I put:-

```
.....
(Select
      1 As level
    union All
    Select
      2
    union All
    Select
      3) level) t Left Join
  child On t.RefID = child.memberid
......
```

where I get my desired output like below:-

```
Id  Name    Date Join   Child
--  ----    ---------   -----
B   BBBB    XX/XX/XX    2
C   CCCC    XX/XX/XX    5
```

By using **Left Join** I can scan and show all Table Child related with RefID either exist on not as Child dataset.

I still need to show child = **0** ***if record not found*** in Table Child instead of null or blank value.

I am very appreciate if yours all can improve this solutions. Maybe have others sql statement more effective and faster than this.

And, please help me to figure out regarding COUNT and SUM on Parent dataset. I still no idea how to overcome this problem yet.

Thanks you.

Comment: I put  { Select Distinc Count(t.RefID) As xr, }  and group {Group By
  t.id, t.RefID, t.level} still not working as what I want. Arrrghhh....